# Example of how to use apparmor's aa-exec?

Tags: apparmor

I'm trying to use aa-exec but can't find any examples.

```
  sudo aa-exec -f home.me.opt.blah.foobin -p home.me.opt.blah.foobin ls
```

(run in the dir /home/me/opt/blah/) yields

```
  aa-exec: ERROR: profile 'home.me.opt.blah.foobin' does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

If `/home/me/opt/blah/foobin` is a profile:

```
sudo aa-exec -p /home/me/opt/blah/foobin ls
```

If `/home/me/opt/blah/foobin` is a file or directory containing profiles:

```
sudo aa-exec -f /home/me/opt/blah/foobin ls
```